# React Native OpenTok - 'OpenTok/OpenTok.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, opentok

I'm trying to build my iOS project in Xcode, but for some reason I now get this OpenTok header file missing error:

```
/node_modules/opentok-react-native/ios/OpenTokReactNative/OpenTokReactNative-Bridging-Header.h:8:9:
 'OpenTok/OpenTok.h' file not found
```

```
Failed to emit precompiled header 
'/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...-hhcmkaqujbymosbeattxthhfmrfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/OpenTokReactNative-Bridging-Header-swift_3UMP1D0ORZMAQ-clang_3HJI1Q08UYJAW.pch' 
for bridging header '/Users/.../.../.../node_modules/opentok-react-native/ios/OpenTokReactNative/OpenTokReactNative-Bridging-Header.h'
```

I've previously completed the OpenTok React Native installation process for [iOS](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native#ios-installation) (i.e. pod install, creating the `.swift` file and bridging header file etc) and it was working fine. But now it can't find the OpenTok header file, even though I can see it under the Pods directory (`./Pods/OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OpenTok.h`).

So far I've removed the Pods directory and the Podfile.lock file and re-run `pod install`, I've cleaned the project in Xcode and re-run the build, but no luck.

The only thing I can think of that I've changed between when i was successfully building and now is upgrading Cocoapods from version 1.4 to 1.6. Would that have anything to do with it?

Can someone give me some pointers on what I can try next to get Xcode to find the `OpenTok.h` file and build successfully?

The versions I'm using are

XCode - 10.1
React Native - 0.57.8
opentok-react-native - 0.9.5
Cocoapods - 1.6.0

** **Update:** **
I've done a bit of digging and noticed that the OpenTok `.h` symlinks are missing from `ios/Pods/Headers/Public/` directory. I've gone ahead and manually created an `OpenTok` directory under `ios/Pods/Headers/Public/` and added these missing symlinks:

```
OpenTok.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OpenTok.h
OTVideoKit.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OTVideoKit.h
OTSubscriberKit.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OTSubscriberKit.h
OTSubscriber.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OTSubscriber.h
OTStream.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OTStream.h
OTSession.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OTSession.h
OTPublisherKit.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OTPublisherKit.h
OTPublisher.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OTPublisher.h
OTNetworkStatsKit.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OTNetworkStatsKit.h
OTError.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OTError.h
OTConnection.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OTConnection.h
OTAudioKit.h -> ../../../OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/Headers/OTAudioKit.h
```

After cleaning the project in Xcode again, it now finds the header files for OpenTok and successfully builds.

So I guess the question is now - what process creates the symlinks for the headers under the `ios/Pods/Headers/OpenTok` directory? and why aren't they being created anymore? Presumably `pod install` creates these?

Comment: Have the same issue, thank you!!!!

Comment: I'm having the same issue = anyone help ?